# Installing from NPM Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, swiper.js

On my task gulp, I try to use the installation of npm packages and use them according to the instructions. I did it with swiper

```
npm install swiper
```

After that, I tried to connect it according to one of the conditions.

```
  // core version + navigation, pagination modules:
     import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

  // configure Swiper to use modules
     Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);
```

AND

```
  // import Swiper bundle with all modules installed
     import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UPD: gulp-browserify That's settled.